# Is There A Function Of Constant Area?

Tags: geometry, functions

If I take a point $(x,y)$ and multiply the coordinates $x\times y$ to find the area $(A)$ defined by the rectangle formed with the axes, then is there a function $f(x)$ so that $xy = A$, regardless of what value of $x$ is chosen?

Comment: Please clarify, what role does $f(x)$ play in your question?

Comment: The hyperbola defined by $y=A/x$ ?

Comment: ha! I feel stupid. Thanks Maesumi.

Comment: Easy question, but actually a nice exercise in intuition and classical analytic geometry.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The curve you are after is the rectangular hyperbola given by the equation $xy=A$. For instance, in the figure below, you see that the red, purple and blue rectangles are all of unit area ($A=1$).

[image]

Comment: What software did you use to make the graph?

Comment: @JoeHobbit The plot was made using [Grapher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grapher) on Mac OS X.

Answer (score 11):

Take any desired real value $A$, then from $xy = A$, define $$f: \mathbb R\setminus \{0\} \to \mathbb R,\quad f(x) = y = \dfrac Ax$$